# Store the content of a txt file into a variable with comma separated

Tags: awk, sed, csv

Hi I have a file txt file with keys

`a.txt`:

```
1234
4567
4568
4564
6754
warning message
invoke from function
```

I need to write the content of this file into a variable parm as

```
1234,4567,3456,2345
```

I need to *omit last two lines* in the file as well.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you planning to write the data to a file? If so, you don't have to store it in a variable first. Also, if you really _need_ to store it in a variable (because you want to use them), it would be better to store the individual values as elements of an array than to store them as values delimited by commas in a single string. Also, where does those `3456` and `2345` values come from?

Comment: i wanted to pass that variable to curl command for list_value attribute, so wanted a single variable which will have a string with values separated by , which can be uploaded.

Comment: @Kusalananda as u said "it would be better to store the individual values as elements of an array than to store them as values delimited by commas in a single string." can u tell me how to do this way..

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `head` or compatible, you can use negative numbers to remove a given number of lines off the end of a file:

```
parm=$(head -n -2 < a.txt | paste -sd , -)
```

With `zsh`:

```
parm=${(j:,:)"${(@f)$(<a.txt)}"[1,-3]}
```

(beware that `$(<a.txt)` strips all trailing newline characters, so would also strip trailing empty lines, and `[1,-3]` remove 2 extra lines).

POSIXly:

```
parm=$(sed '$d' < a.txt | sed '$d' | paste -sd , -)
```

Or with `awk`:

```
parm=$(awk 'NR>2 {printf "%s",  sep b; sep = ","}
            {b = a; a = $0}' < a.txt)
```

Comment: i need to 2 things, 1- ommit last two lines, 2- store the content in a variable with coma in a shell script

Comment: @akr, all those solutions should do just that.

Comment: awk worked perfectly :) thx a lot... can u pls explain me dat..

Comment: can u explain me the awk command..

Comment: wat if i do not want to ignore last 2 lines... how to change the awk code fro this.. @stephane

Comment: @akr, then it's just `param=$(paste -sd , a.txt)`